# ffmpeg side by side video

Tags: ffmpeg

Im trying to get two 1080p videos side by side,  Wanting the two scaled to 720p and combined both as 1080p

ive tried using the below code . it works fine when using the lower resolution but when i try to make it go higher it gets all mixed up

any tips

`ffmpeg -i video.avi -i video2.avi -filter_complex "nullsrc=size=720x288 [base]; [0:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=360x288 [left]; [1:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=360x288 [right]; [base][left] overlay=shortest=1 [tmp1]; [tmp1][right] overlay=shortest=1:x=360:y=0" -c:v libx264 -f flv "rtmp://192.168.1.1/live/videocrop"`

Comment: *when i try to make it go higher it gets all mixed up* --> how do you change the command?

Comment: by changing nullsrc=size=720x288 and the two scale=360x288 but guessing im doing it wrong lol  any ideas how to get it higher resolution per video

Comment: Eg. ffmpeg -i video.avi -i video2.avi -filter_complex "nullsrc=size=1920x1080 [base]; [0:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=1280x720 [left]; [1:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=1280x720 [right]; [base][left] overlay=shortest=1 [tmp1]; [tmp1][right] overlay=shortest=1:x=360:y=0" -c:v libx264 -f flv "rtmp://192.168.1.1/live/videocrop"

Answer (score 1):

Just use [hstack](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#hstack):

```
ffmpeg -i video.avi -i video2.avi -filter_complex "[0:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=360x288 [left]; [1:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=360x288 [right]; [left][right]hstack=inputs=2" -c:v libx264 -f flv rtmp://192.168.1.1/live/videocrop
```

Comment: thanks that works,  Now just run into this problem lol
https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/7547

Comment: @rodreguoussmith I'm assuming your build uses `--enable-librtmp`. The native FFmpeg RTMP implementation apparently is not affected by that bug. You may have to re-complile without `--enable-librtmp` to be able to use the native RTMP.

Comment: thanks  yeah seems that annoying bug is doing it,   are there any other protocols that could do the same job besides RTMP

Comment: @rodreguoussmith I'm not sure. I never got interested in streaming protocols. I suggest trying the native RTMP implementation before anything else.